# how to convert a list to a default dictionary

Tags: python

I want to convert a list to a default dictionary to have a default value of 0 in case the key doesn't have any value (from the list).

list : `order = ['a',1,'b',2,'c']`

what I did using ZIP :

```
it = iter(order)
res_dict = dict(zip(it,it))
print(res_dict)
```

but it excludes c as a key, as the list doesn't have the next index after c.

Result I got : `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

Result i want : `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}`

Comment: How do you handle the next key? Eg `['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3]`, how do you recognize that `d` is a key and not a value?

Comment: Yeah !! didn't think that code will consider d as a value, not as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using `itertools` and `.zip_longest()`.

For example:

```
import itertools
l = ['a',1,'b',2,'c']
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(l[::2], l[1::2], fillvalue=0))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
```

Comment: You don't need the slices, the questioner's iterator code can work with `zip_longest` too.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes it's working for me without slicing

Comment: ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', 3] in this case it would take d as a value, not as a key, how to handle this one?  any suggestions?

Comment: @sharma_re: That's a lot more complicated. You didn't describe what the logic is supposed to be to distinguish keys and values. Presumably strings are keys and numbers are values, but is that all you can get? What if there's some other kind of value in the list, is that an error?

Comment: @Blckknght Yes! it wasn't mentioned in the question, this is something that I just saw in the comments though it's only going to be string type for a key. guessing checking the data type of next item would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
d = dict()
    
    for i in range(len(order)):
        if i%2==0 and i+1<len(order):
            d[order[i]] =order[i+1]
        elif i+2>(len(order)):
            d[order[i]]=0
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of two consequent keys you can use a custom function to split the list

```
def splitdefault(o):
    i = 0

    while i < len(o):

        # there is a next element to check
        if i + 1 < len(o):

            # the next element is int
            if isinstance(o[i + 1], int):
                yield o[i], o[i + 1]
                i += 2

            else:
                yield o[i], 0
                i += 1

        # i is the last element
        else:
            yield o[i], 0
            i += 1

order = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", "d", 3, "e"]


for g in splitdefault(order):
    print(g)

res_dict = dict(splitdefault(order))
print(res_dict)
```

Which produces

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 3, 'e': 0}
```

Cheers!